# Error while importing from a parent directory

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

env.py running normally, but when I execute "`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "create models"`" in cmd it throws an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'`.

the imports:

```
import sys
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)

from data import Base  # noqa: E402
```

the structure of folders:

mainfolder

> migrations
>
> > env.py

tried this, as shown above:

```
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
```

but it only works when running env.py manually somewhy

Comment: Do you have a `data.py` file that defines `Base`, or a `data/Base.py` file you want to load? In the later case, in order for `data/` to be considered a module by Python, it has to have a `__init__.py` file. Run `touch data/__init__.py` and then, if `data/Base.py` exists, your import statement should work.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by running:

```
mkdir data
touch data/Base.py
```

The line `from data import Base` means Python will look for a folder called `data` which should contain `Base.py`. I don't see that in your folder structure.